# Plot a specific branch of a multi-valued complex function

Tags: plotting, complex

Let's say I want to plot a branch of the following function $f(z) = \sqrt{z(z-1)}$. Let $z = r_1 e^{i\theta_1}$ and $z-1 = r_2 e^{i\theta_2}$.

How can I tell *Mathematica* to plot the branch for which $0 \leq \theta_1 < 2\pi$ and $-\pi \leq \theta_2 < \pi$?

Comment: What sort of plot do you want?

Comment: I would like a 3D plot :)

Answer (score 1):

To visualize the Riemann surface of $\sqrt{z(z-1)}$ over the OP's chosen domain, do a preliminary analysis with `Reduce[]`:

```
Reduce[-π <= Arg[r E^(I θ) - 1] < π && 0 <= θ < 2 π && r >= 0] // FullSimplify
   (r > 0 && (π < θ < 2 π || 0 < θ < π)) || (r == 1 && θ == 0) ||
   (r > 1 && (0 <= θ < ArcSec[r] || (θ + ArcSec[r] > 2 π && θ < 2 π)))
```

whose result you can then use to construct the `RegionFunction` to be used in `ParametricPlot3D[]`:

```
ParametricPlot3D[{r Cos[θ], r Sin[θ], Im[Sqrt[r Exp[I θ] (r Exp[I θ] - 1)]]},
                 {r, 0, 4}, {θ, 0, 2 π}, 
                 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z, r, θ},
                                            (r > 0 &&
                                             (0 < θ < π || π < θ < 2 π)) ||
                                            (r > 1 &&
                                             (0 <= θ < ArcSec[r] ||
                                              2 π - ArcSec[r] < θ < 2 π))]]
```

[image: Riemann surface of \sqrt{z(z-1)}]

Answer (score 0):

In a first step you can eliminate r1 ,r2:

```
erg = 
  Simplify[
    ExpToTrig[Solve[1 - r2 Exp[I θ2] == r1 Exp[I θ1], Element[{r1, r2}, Reals]]], 
    {Element[{θ1, θ2}, Reals], 0 <= θ1 < 2 Pi, -Pi <= θ2 < Pi}][[1]]
```

> ```
> {r1 -> -Csc[θ1 - θ2] Sin[θ2], r2 -> Csc[θ1 - θ2] Sin[θ1]}
> ```

With this result `f[z]` evaluates to

```
Csc[θ1 - θ2]^2 Sin[θ1] Sin[θ2] (Cos[θ1 + θ2] + I Sin[θ1 + θ2])
```

and can be plotted in the parameter space of θ1 and θ2.

0
down vote

If x,y depend on teta1, teta2 you can use the function ParametricPlot3D[] with the two parameters teta1, teta2 as arguments to plot f[x+i y].

Sorry, I(as a new user...) don't know why, but I'm not allowed to comment your notes. Though I have to edit my answer:

You're right with the correction.
The two surfaces in your plot probably are the real and imaginary part of f. You've to specify the output in your plot , for example Abs[f]!

Comment: How can I plot it in the space $(x,y,w)$ with $w=f(z)=f(x+iy)$?

Comment: 1) In your `Solve` function, I think it should be `r2 Exp[I θ2] + 1== r1 Exp[I θ1] ` 2) I tried to plot the function using `ParametricPlot3D` but it gives me an multiple surfaces although it should give me only one branch of the function : `ParametricPlot3D[{-Csc[θ1 - θ2] Sin[θ2] Cos[θ1], -Csc[θ1 - θ2] Sin[θ2] Sin[θ1],
   Re[f[-Csc[θ1 - θ2] Sin[θ2], -Csc[θ1 - θ2] Sin[θ1], θ1, θ2]]}, {θ1, 0, 
  2 Pi}, {θ2, -Pi, Pi}]` with `f[r1_, r2_, θ1_, θ2_] = 
 Sqrt[r1*r2]*Exp[I *(θ1+θ2)/2]`

Comment: **Note** : I used the fact that `x = r1 Cos[θ1] = -Csc[θ1 - θ2] Sin[θ2] Cos[θ1]` and `y = r1 Sin[θ1] = -Csc[θ1 - θ2] Sin[θ2] Sin[θ1]` for the inputs of the `ParametricPlot3D` function.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite clear what you want but as a first stage why not just plot the modulus (which will be continuous) and the argument (phase) which will show jumps.

```
   Plot3D[Evaluate[Abs[Sqrt[z (z - 1)]] /. z -> x + I y], {x, -2, 
      2}, {y, -2, 2}]
    Plot3D[Evaluate[Arg[Sqrt[z (z - 1)]] /. z -> x + I y], {x, -2, 
      2}, {y, -2, 2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

What exactly do you wish to do? Do you wish to have the plot continued beyond the jump edges?

Hope that helps.